# How to read web service header information from Java/Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a WSDL that contains a few header elements as well as the main body with the operation. How do I access the header elements from my web service (I'm using axis 2)?

Just in case that makes no sense, here's a cut down version of a request:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <ser:ServiceContext>
     <ser:From>?</ser:From>
  </ser:ServiceContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <gen:DoSomething>
     <gen:InputDetails>
        <gen:Target>?</gen:Target>
     </gen:InputDetails>
  </gen:DoSomething>
</soapenv:Body>
```

The stub has generated the following for me to use as a test client:

```
public DoSomethingResponse doSomething(
   InputDetails inputDetails,
   ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

And the skeleton code to receive the web request is:

```
public DoSomethingResponse doSomething(
   InputDetails inputDetails)
```

So from within the doSomething method I want to access the header data for ser:From, I can see all the code and generated data types but I have no idea how to access the data (ServiceContext header) as the server side code only takes in the data passed to the operation.

thanks.